# adding <br> in certain array index - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am making a calculator program with javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var buttonname = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "+", "-", "*", "/", "C", "Enter"];
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var n = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < buttonname.length; i++) {
        document.write("<button>" + buttonname[i] + "</button>");
        if (i = 3 * n, n++)
            document.write("<button>" + buttonname[i] + "</button><br>");
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output should be something like this:

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

9 0 + -

- / C Enter

but my output is

1 2 4

5 7

8 0

- *

/ Enter

what is the problem? I see 3,6,9,-,C buttons are disappeared but why? I just wanna make a new line when for loop passes the 3*n indexes. (Means new line after button 4,8 ... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your if block, the logic appears to be broken.
Replace it with the if block below and you will be good to go.

```
if( (i+1) %3 == 0)
document.write("<br />");
```

This checks if the running index is a multiple of 3 and if so inserts newline. i+1 is required because your loops starts with 0.

You must pay special attention to the way you have structured & written your code. Sorry to say you have bad 'code handwriting'.

Output SS[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0eG6.png)

This [JavaScript array tutorial](http://codingraptor.com/javascript/arrays-in-javascript/) is pretty nice, and has well formatted code as well.

Comment: Thank you everybody for fast answers!

Answer (score 1):

`document.write` is a terrible way to add dynamic content to a web page, but that point aside your logic is just wrong

> I just wanna make a new line when for loop passes the 3*n indexes

What you actually want is a `<br/>` after every 4th element in the array

```
for(var i = 0; i <buttonname.length; i++){
    if(i != 0 && (i%4) == 0)
       document.write("<br>");
    document.write("<button>"+buttonname[i]+"</button>");        
}
```

```js
var buttonname = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","+","-","*","/","C","Enter"];

var n=0;
for(var i = 0; i <buttonname.length; i++){
    if(i != 0 && (i%4) == 0)
       document.write("<br>");
    document.write("<button>"+buttonname[i]+"</button>");
}
```

Comment: Thank you everybody for fast answers!

Answer (score 0):

What about using [`modulo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) ?

```
var buttonname = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "+", "-", "*", "/", "C", "Enter"];

for (var i = 0; i < buttonname.length; i++) {
    document.write("<button>" + buttonname[i] + "</button>");
    if (i % 4 == 3) {
        document.write("<br>");
    }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5d67jm7f/1/)

Comment: Thank you everybody for fast answers!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script type="text/javascript">
var buttonname = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","+","-","*","/","C","Enter"];
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var n=0;
for(var i = 0; i <buttonname.length; i++){
document.write("<button>"+buttonname[i]+"</button>");
if(i!=0 && (i+1)%3==0)
  document.write("<br>");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you everybody for fast answers!